# Trouble handling all errors in Telegraf js (TelegramError: 400: Bad Request: message to delete not found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf.js

I have a button in a telegraf telegram bot that call this action

```
bot.action("clear", async ctx => {
    let id = (await bot.telegram.sendMessage(ctx.chat.id, "Clearing console")).message_id;
    console.log(id);
    for(let i = 0; i <= 100; i++ ){
        try {
            ctx.deleteMessage(id - i);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

But when I click the button that calls the action above, I have this error and Nodemon crashes :
`TelegramError: 400: Bad Request: message to delete not found`

I already have these lines

```
const bot: Telegraf<Context> = new Telegraf(token);

bot.catch(err => {
    console.log("Ooops, encountered an error", err);
});
```

How can I fix this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you could use  `ctx.sendMessage("Your message")` , in order to send message back. Also try to use statement with **await** keyword `await ctx.deleteMessage(id - i)`.